# How to implement multithreading while reading a file that has multiline record in Spring Batch

Tags: multithreading, spring-batch, multiline

We are loading a large file using Spring Batch. The file has ticket data and each ticket data spans multiple lines. The end of a ticket data is identified by the beginning of the next ticket data. And we are using PeekableItemReader for this. The question - Is it possible to implement multithreading to improve the performance of the reader when we can't process one record at a time? Multiple threads should not read different parts (lines) of same ticket data as they have to be read and processed in a single thread. Our aim is to improve the performance of the reader

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your aggregate item reader (the one that reads all lines of a single ticket) in a [SynchronizedItemStreamReader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/SynchronizedItemStreamReader.html) and use it safely in a multi-threaded step.

Comment: Hi, I implemented a Custom Reader that implements ItemStreamReader and in the read method, it reads and return the multiple lines as a custom object (Ticket). This works fine in Single thread and the tickets (multiple records) are returned correctly and processed. But when I wrap the custom reader using SynchronizedItemStreamReader it is not reading safely. The records are read in random order and resulting error.

Comment: public SynchronizedItemStreamReader<BSPBaseRecord>  getReader() {
    SynchronizedItemStreamReader<BSPBaseRecord>  synchronizedItemStreamReader = new SynchronizedItemStreamReader<BSPBaseRecord>();
    synchronizedItemStreamReader.setDelegate(bspItemReader);
    return synchronizedItemStreamReader;
}
The bspItemReader works well in single threaded mode when not wrapped in SynchronizedItemStreamReader